# Film or TV movie involving an elderly lady who raises her cane into the air and transforms into an alien

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm looking for a movie that I watched as a kid, but I can't remember what it's called. Here's some information that might help:

- The film or TV movie can be from the 1980s to the early '90s.
- I remember an elderly lady who raises her cane into the air and transforms into an alien (a god alien). Although the film is live action, there's some animation when the older lady transforms into an alien. I also remember the older lady who is an alien fighting two other aliens in the end of the film.
- Furthermore, I remember that there is a girl in the film who gets green eyes and who can do some kind of telekinesis. She tries to protect a small child so as not to get the same green eyes.
- I'm pretty sure it's an American science fiction movie in color.

Comment: How all those aliens look like? Was there any weapons, chemistry, beams, spaceships?

Comment: This is live action not animated (except for special effects)?

Comment: Makes me think of June & Anne Lockhart in Troll ('86). When the evil takes over the house, elderly June who is the protector transforms into the younger version of herself (played by her daughter Anne). The little girl in the story is possessed by the troll, and there's an older brother trying to help her.

Answer (score 2):

Some, but not all of this sounds like John Carpenter's 1995 Film *[Village of the Damned](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114852/)*.  It was the second adaptation of the 1957 novel *The Midwich Cuckoos* by John Wyndham, after the (probably more famous) 1960 version.  The stuff about the children matches, but not the element of a elderly woman transforming into an alien to fight two other aliens.

Here's the trailer (featuring Superman, Luke Skywalker, and Lt. Saavik).

*Village of the Damned* features children with evil psychic powers; they are possessed by some kind of aliens or monsters, and their eyes glow (most often green, but sometimes other colors) when the powers are in use.  There are attempts to protect one of the children from being taken over and controlled by these entities.

The plot, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village_of_the_Damned_(1995_film)):

> The people and animals of the sleepy coastal town of Midwich in California's Marin County fall asleep at a 10 AM "blackout" and regain consciousness at 4 PM. Following the blackout, ten women are mysteriously pregnant, including a virgin girl and a married woman who has not been sexually active for a year due to her husband being away for work in Tokyo. None of them seek abortions after having dreams, and all the babies are born the same night in a barn – five boys and five girls, though the virgin's daughter is stillborn due to umbilical asphyxia. The surviving children are healthy but have pale skin, white-blonde hair, cobalt eyes, and fierce intellect.
>
> However, they do not appear to possess a conscience or individual personalities. They display eerie psychic powers that can result in violent and deadly consequences whenever they experience pain or provocation. The children soon "pair off" like mates, except for David, whose intended mate was the stillborn girl. As a result, David is the outcast of the group. Although he retains some degree of psychic powers, he also has the ability to show human compassion. He talks to his mother, Jill McGowan, the school principal, and begins to understand his situation. The children's leader is Mara, the daughter of the physician, Dr. Alan, and his wife, Barbara. As a baby, Mara used her powers to force her mother to commit suicide by jumping off a cliff. Her mate is Robert.
>
> The children, who now have a bad reputation in town, eventually move to the local barn as their classroom for survival. Local priest Father George attempts to shoot them, only for Mara to use her powers and force George to shoot himself. Soon, it is learned that there are other colonies of blackout children in foreign countries, but due to their inhuman nature, they were quickly eliminated, in some cases at the cost of destroying the entire town. The scientific team in Midwich flees the town to escape the chaos. One of the scientists, Dr. Susan Verner, is forced to show the children the well-preserved alien corpse of David's intended mate she secretly kept for research. The children force her to stab herself. An angry mob gathers to kill the children, but the town descends into chaos.